# Are there any alternative RSS Gadget for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, rss, desktop-gadget, feed-reader

I would like to have a minimalistic RSS Feed Reader for my Windows 7. For that, I think a Gadget would be a good fit. And there is the default [RSS Gadget](http://video.about.com/windows/How-to-Use-the-RSS-Gadget.htm). But it is really bad, because it's animated all the time, and this really distracts me, so I can't use it. It's OK (or good) if the gadget is animated when the RSS Feed is updated, but as long as the RSS Feed isn't updated it should just stay calm and not distract my work.

Are there any alternative RSS Gadget for Windows 7? (that are't distracting) Or any other minimalistic RSS Feed Reader, that can notify me for updates?

Answer (score 2):

Apologies for the blatant self promotion :)

You could try [hermesgadget.codeplex.com](http://hermesgadget.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) and turn scrolling off.
Also delete all read items (Ctrl-Alt + Right Mouse button), so nothing to distract you until new items arrive.

Comment: I was looking for an alternative windows gadget and this fits the bill nicely. I'm not sure how to turn the scrolling off (perhaps Display -> Scroll rate = 0 ?).

Comment: I can't figure this application out, I just get "You need to select a category first" with no clear indication of how to do that. The manual doesn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of being distracting,
I suggest you plug in your RSS feeds into the Google Reader and, start a Google Chrome session to view them. It is quite minimalistic in a sense and very comfortable to navigate.

Alternatively, check [RSSOwl](http://www.rssowl.org/overview2).

Answer (score 0):

There is [FeedFlow](https://code.google.com/p/feedflow/) that I haven't updates for a while. Has some nice features that you can see if you navigate to the link.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Rainmeter to setup a nice desktop with rss feeds. It uses really low resources but needs some configuration to set up.

[Rainmeter](http://www.rainmeter.net)

Otherwise just use Firefox addons or Chrome extensions. I'd recommend either Digg Reader or Feedly.